# Multithreded udp-Server vs. Non blocking calls

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, udp

First questions here. I gave searched for this but haven't found any solution which fully answers my problem here. I'm using c++ and need to write a kind of usp chat (server and client) for programs to interact with one another. Well atm it works quite well.

I'm using Googles protobuf as Messages.

I've written it like that:

Server has a list of users curently logged in as well as a list of messages to process and distrubute.

One thread handles all receiving on its socket (I'm using one socket).
If command var in the message is login,
It looks through the list and checks for this combination of port and IP. If not in, the chat creates a new user entry.

If command logout, the server looks for the user in list and deletes it.

If command is message, the server looks if user is logged in and puts it on the message list.

The 2nd thread is for sending.
It waits till there is a message in the list and then cycles through all users to send this messages to their sockets except the sending one.

The server has set options on its socket to receive from any ip.

My question now is: is this the most performat solution?
I've read about select and poll. But it's always about multiple receiving sockets while I have only one.
I know the receiving thread may be idling all the time but in my environment there would be a high frequent message input.

I'm fairly new to socket programming but I think this was the most elegant solution. I was wondering if I could even create another thread which gets a list from receiving thread to process the messages.

Edit: how could I detect time outs?
I mean I could have a variable in the user list which increases or get set to 0. But what if messages won't come frequently. Maybe a server based ping message? Or maybe a flag on the message which get set to acknowledged and gets resend.

On the user side I need to first broadcast to find the server and then set port and up accordingly to the answer. How could I do that?

Because this should run autonomous. Meaning a client should detect dmthe server, login, sends its commands and detect wether it is still online.

On server side I don't know if this is so important. Possibly there might be a memory issue if there are too many things connected and non get logged off. Maybe I set a 1 h timeout to let it detect idle clients.

Comment: You should in fact have another thread processing the message, or even better have a thread pool. The messages should be handed over through a thread safe producer / consumer queue.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for your reply. That is what I thought to be best as the processing itself could lead to step over an incoming message.